# How to prevent EntityType to display current object in a ManyToOne relationship to the same Entity (Parent)?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, sonata

I have an entity with a `ManyToOne` relationship to itself, since it their objects can have parents of the same kind.

I extended an `EntityType` to display the objects from the Entity, but I don't want the current object to be displayed in the choice list, since an object cannot be parent of itself.

To filter an object by its owner, I'm doing something like this

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefault('query_builder', function (Options $options) {
        return function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('con')
                ->orderBy('con.name', 'ASC')
                ->andWhere('con.owner = :owner')
                ->setParameter('owner', $this->getLoggedUser());
        };
    });
}
```

But I have no idea of how to get the current object to add an `andWhere` clause to remove it from the choice list.

So, any idea how can I remove the object being edited from the choice list in an EntityType?

Comment: so, you want con != loggedUser? then ... just `->andWhere('con != :owner')` (since it's the owner same in this very special case) or am I missing something?

Comment: No, I have the logged user.Lets say the entity is Folder. The owner creates FolderA and FolderB. The entitytype will list FolderA and FolderB to be chosen as FolderB parents, what doesn't make sense. I want to get exclude the object being edited from the entity list. This is my real code https://github.com/devaneando/CWCompanion/blob/master/src/Admin/Type/ProjectType.php

Comment: I assume your repo is private ;o) however, you could inject the "parent" object via the options and use it in your function to filter it out, no?

Comment: Not at all. Maybe some typpo: https://github.com/devaneando/CWCompanion/blob/master/src/Admin/Type/OwnerAware/ConceptType.php

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix your current code you could use the `$options['data']`, as it holds the form's underlying data. I believe in your case that would be the (e.g.) `Folder` entity. Try this (note that here I assume that the underlying entity is persisted):

```php
$resolver->setDefault('query_builder', function (Options $options) {
    return function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('con')
            ->orderBy('con.name', 'ASC')
            ->andWhere('con != :current')
            ->andWhere('con.owner = :owner')
            ->setParameter('current', $options['data'])
            ->setParameter('owner', $this->getLoggedUser())
        ;
    };
});
```

If the underlying entity might not be persisted yet (so for example when adding a new `Folder`), you have to slightly modify the code to account for that:

```php
$resolver->setDefault('query_builder', function (Options $options) {
    return function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
        $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('con')
            ->andWhere('con.owner = :owner')
            ->setParameter('owner', $this->getLoggedUser())
            ->orderBy('con.name', 'ASC')
        ;

        $current = $options['data'];
        if (null !== $current->getId()) {
            $qb
                ->andWhere('con != :current')
                ->setParameter('current', $options['data'])
            ;
        }

        return $qb;
    };
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [michał-tomczuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3455675/micha%C5%82-tomczuk) and thanks [jakumi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4275413/jakumi), you both were very helpful but I guess your suggestions didn't work because the `FormType` is created before the `AdminType` and the 'data' isn't available in options the context yet. At least I couldn't find it anywhere.

I tried another approach that worked, even if it's kinda of overkill.

Since a formtype is always used in editing context and, in my case, under SonataAdmin scope, I injected the router into the type and filtered the query by the object id I was able to retrieve from the PathInfo:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

/** @var RouterInterface $router */
private $router;  


/** {@inheritdoc} */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefault('query_builder', function (Options $options) {
        return function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
            $matches = [];
            preg_match(
                '/^.*\/([0-9a-z\-]+)\/edit$/',
                $this->router->getContext()->getPathInfo(),
                $matches
            );

            $queryBuilder = $er->createQueryBuilder('ent')
                ->orderBy('ent.name', 'ASC')
            if (true === array_key_exists('1', $matches)) {
                $queryBuilder
                    ->andWhere('ent.id != :id')
                    ->setParameter('id', $matches[1]);
            }
            return $queryBuilder;
        };
    });
}
```

I know it's a dirty solution but works.

Comment: out of curiosity: when trying to provide the parent object via the `$options`, you should probably not set it as `data` but as something not yet reserved, like ... "myparent" or something, which you'd have to add to the `$resolver` with `$resolver->setDefined(['myparent'])` or `setRequired` or `setDefault`, such that the OptionsResolver doesn't choke on it. (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html) I feel like, that approach would be cleaner

Comment: Going to check it. Thanks!